# what are the parameters mandateory to dispatchEvent?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

```
// Init and load product
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_init_before', array(
    'controller_action' => $controller,
    'params' => $params,
));
```

magento always dispatches events like the above. Is it necessary to pass the `$controller` and `$params` to the `Mage::dispatchEvent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mandatory parameter to the `Mage::dispatchEvent` method is the event name (the first parameter).
The second parameter is an optional array containing the data that you want to pass to the event observer.
There is no rule to what you should pass to the observer.
It can be anything you find useful.
And it depends on what you want the observer to handle.
If you are in a model context, maybe you want to pass the model instance.
If you are in a controller maybe you want to pass the get parameters.
But there is no general rule.